# Mongoose pre validate/save has this = undefined in plugin

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Given simple plugin:

```
//plugin.js
module.exports = function (schema, options) {
  schema.pre('save', function (done) {
    console.log(this);
    done();
  });
  schema.pre('validate', function (done) {
    console.log(this);
    done();
  });
}
```

And simple usage of it:

```
//test.js
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    plugin = require('./plugin');

describe('Example', function () { 
  beforeEach(connectToDb); // its a just example. code is pretty simple and should not be mentioned here 
  afterEach(disconnectDb);

  it('should save', function (done) {
    var scheme = new mongoose.Schema({
      'prop' : String
    });
    scheme.plugin(plugin);
    var model = mongoose.model('model', scheme);
    var modelInstance = new model({ 'prop' : 'value' });
    modelInstance.save(function (err) {
      assert(!err);
      done();
  });
```

What happens here? After running this code I got:

```
undefined
undefined
```

Any thoughts about it? Why setting undefined? Version of mongoose is `4.2.4`.

Comment: All you've done is require the file `plugin.js`, you haven't actually USED the plugin.

Comment: Right, just a typo :)

Comment: This works fine when I try it outside of the test runner. The document being saved and validated gets logged both times.

Comment: Well maybe its a runner issue? I will check it.